# How to use IF UPDATE() in trigger to avoid update, if there is no change

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have 2 tables:

**RegionDetail**

```
 RegionDetailID
 RegionName
 Sales
 MailSentID
```

**RegionDetailHistory**

```
 RegionDetailHistoryID 
 RegionDetailID
 Sales
 MailSentID
```

When I insert/ update in `RegionDetail`, a trigger is fired and inserts / updates record in `RegionDetailHistory`. It apply to all column changes in `RegionDetail` except for `MailSentID`. For `MailSentID`, the value should be `NULL` in the history table if there is no update for this value in the `RegionDetail`.

For example: I inserted a record into `RegionDetail` with these values:

```
RegionName | Sales | MailSentID 
-----------+-------+----------- 
Hyderabad  | 9000  | 1
```

The trigger will insert the record into `RegionDetail` as shown here:

```
RegionDetailHistoryID   | RegionDetailID  | Sales | MailSentID
------------------------+-----------------+-------+-----------
1                       |        1        | 9000  | 1
```

Now I update Sales to 9500 in `RegionDetail` where `RegionID = 1`

Updated result:

```
RegionDetailHistoryID | RegionDetailID | Sales | MailSentID 
----------------------+----------------+-------+----------- 
           2          |        1       | 9500  | 1
```

Expected result:

```
RegionDetailHistoryID | RegionDetailID | Sales | MailSentID 
----------------------+----------------+-------+----------- 
           2          |        1       | 9500  | NULL
```

`MailSentID` should be `NULL` as there is no update for this value in `RegionDetail` table. If it is updated from value 1 to some other value 2 then It can be with value 2 in the above table instead of NULL.

I have this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_RegionDetail_IU] 
ON [dbo].[RegionDetail]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.RegionDetailHistory (RegionDetailID, Sales)
        SELECT RegionDetailID, Sales
        FROM inserted.

    DECLARE @HistoryID INT, @MailSentID INT

    SELECT TOP 1 @HistoryID = RegionDetailHistoryID
    FROM [dbo].[RegionDetailHistory]
    ORDER BY RegionDetailHistoryID DESC

    SELECT @MailsentID = MailSentID
    FROM inserted
   
    IF UPDATE (MailSentID)
       UPDATE RH
       SET MailsentID = @MailSentID
       FROM [RegionDetailHistory] RH
       WHERE [RegionDetailHistoryID] = @HistoryID
```

But it is inserting the `MailSentID` with value into the history table, even though there is no change for this `MailSentID` in `RegionDetail` table.

Could anyone please suggest, the way this can be done?

Thank you

Comment: `SELECT @MailsentID = MailSentID FROM inserted` -> [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: `UPDATE(Column)` is true if the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement inserted or updated the column *at all*. It does not care if the value of the column changed for some row (or none at all); for that you need to inspect the state of the table before the update through the `deleted` pseudo-table. (If an insert happened, there's nothing in `deleted`.) Plus, per Aaron, every trigger must always be written to handle *multiple* rows.

Comment: Your current logic makes no sense - ignoring the other issues. You insert all the affected rows (from inserted) into your history table. You then retrieve mail ID from the inserted table. And then you update rows in the history table with that value - which would not actually change anything in the affected history row. I suggest this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and that you are attempting to use / manipulate the history table for a very different purpose than just "history".

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 @HistoryID = RegionDetailHistoryID` This is not how you retrieve the identity value of any row that your process just inserted if your table has one.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation for the UPDATE() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql), this function *"indicates whether an INSERT or UPDATE attempt was made on a specified column"*. This is based on the columns which are specified in the `UPDATE` statement, not on the actual values which are changed: *"the UPDATED value will return as true or 1, even if the column value remains unchanged."*

In other words, the `UPDATE()` function would return 0 only if the `UPDATE` statement would not contain that column in the `SET` clause.

To check if the values were actually changed, you should use the `inserted` and `deleted` tables, see [Use the inserted and deleted tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables) for more details.

Another issue in your code is that you also should handle statements that affect multiple rows, because the triggers are called once per statement, not once per each affected row. See [Create DML Triggers to Handle Multiple Rows of Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/create-dml-triggers-to-handle-multiple-rows-of-data) for more details.

A better trigger (that handles multiple rows and checks if the `MailSentID` column is actually updated) could be like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_RegionDetail_IU] ON [dbo].[RegionDetail]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF @@ROWCOUNT>0 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.RegionDetailHistory (RegionDetailID, Sales, MailSentID)
    SELECT RegionDetailID, Sales, 
        CASE WHEN i.MailSentID<>d.MailSentID 
            OR i.MailSentID IS NOT NULL AND d.MailSentID IS NULL
            THEN i.MailSentID
            ELSE NULL
        END AS MailSentID
    FROM inserted i LEFT JOIN deleted d ON i.RegionDetailID=d.RegionDetailID
END
```